# Reorder dataframe with two column factors in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have this data frame, where we can see in Column names the factors each observation belongs to.
[image]

And I would like to get a new data frame reordering the previous one, something like this:
[image]

I tried using the reshape package, but something's missing. Anybody?

Comment: Try `data.frame(Count = c(t(dataset)), do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(dataset), "_")))`

Comment: Or with `gather` i.e. `gather(Dataset, key, Count) %>% separate(key, into = c('Factor_1', 'Factor_2'))`

Comment: Awesome!! It worked nice! How could it be in case we know that column 1 is A and X, 2 is A and B, and we could not be able no identify for their column names?

Comment: If you need it in the same order `rownames_to_column(Dataset, 'rn') %>% gather(key, Count, -rn) %>% separate(key, into = c('Factor_1', 'Factor_2')) %>% arrange(Factor_1, rn) %>% select(-rn)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option with `tidyverse` would be to `gather` the columns into 'long', then `separate` the 'key' column into two column and do an `arrange`

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(Dataset, 'rn') %>% 
    gather(key, Count, -rn) %>% 
    separate(key, into = c('Factor_1', 'Factor_2')) %>% 
    arrange(Factor_1, rn) %>%
    select(Count, Factor_1, Factor_2)
#   Count Factor_1 Factor_2
#1      1        A        X
#2      4        A        Y
#3      2        A        X
#4      3        A        Y
#5      5        B        X
#6      8        B        Y
#7      6        B        X
#8      7        B        Y
#9      9        C        X
#10    12        C        Y
#11    10        C        X
#12    11        C        Y
```

---

or with `base R`

```
res <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split.default(Dataset, sub("_.*", "", names(Dataset))), 
    function(x) data.frame(Count = c(t(x)), 
    read.table(text = rep(names(x), nrow(x)), header = FALSE, sep="_"))))
row.names(res) <- NULL
```

#### data

```
Dataset <- structure(list(A_X = 1:2, A_Y = c(4L, 3L), B_X = 5:6, B_Y = c(8L, 
7L), C_X = 9:10, C_Y = c(12L, 11L)), .Names = c("A_X", "A_Y", 
"B_X", "B_Y", "C_X", "C_Y"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```